# Post-mortem .Net debugging

Tags: .net, debugging, vb6, clr

Added a .Net component (C#, COM interop) to an old VB6 application. The old application crashes sometimes (access violation), before and after the change. The difference however is that the post-mortem debugger (i.e. drwtsn32.exe) is not started anymore.
Catching the error in C# is not an option as the bug is not part of the .Net call stack, so MyHandler is not triggered either:

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
```

How to trigger post-mortem debugging again?
Thanks in advance for any help! GMore

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx

Comment: Some additional information: the problem occurs randomly and rarely on one of the 1500 installations.

Comment: @HansPassant Does this mean that there is no post mortem debug anymore? Hopefully there is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProcDump works fine as a post mortem debugger on the XP-systems (where the problem occurs), while drwtsn32 fails if a .net is part of application. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can configure the Registry such that a debugger / dumper will run on crash. More details on Google (see [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well as [Configuring Automatic Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).
2. As Hans Passant mentioned, some tools can aid you with the issue by creating a dump on 2nd-chance exceptions (but those are less useful if the error is random and rare as you say): ProcDump (SysInternals), ADPlus (Debugging Tools for Windows).